# Can't set SplashScreen for Landscape orientation in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, landscape

I have image size of 480*320. I want to set it as Default splash for my application.

I read all blogs, I did everything they said, but I failed to launch my app with landscape mode splash.

I succeed to launch the application in landscape mode but splash is still appearing in Portrait mode.

Help me with This.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't yet bumped up to the newest version of XCode/iOS, but as of XCode 4.x/iOS 5 there was only one image placeholder for splash screen, meaning that you'd have to choose an orientation by way of how you design your splash image (usually the same orientation as how you'd use the app by default).

Comment: @Brian:"meaning that you'd have to choose an orientation by way of how you design your splash image (usually the same orientation as how you'd use the app by default)."Can you elaborate it more.

Comment: I rotate the image and Its done. Thank you Brian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rotate your image in an external editor. Just because you perceive it as landscape doesn't mean it's actually not "rotated portrait".

In short, draw your splash screens as if they are portrait, but draw them sideways!

[image]
[image]

```
        File in Finder                       Image On Simulator
```

---

[image] [image]

```
        File in Finder                        Image On Simulator
```

Images reproduced with kind permission from [AceViral.com](http://aceviral.com)

Comment: No need to thank, just accept an answer if it helped you by clicking the little green checkmark and optionally upvoting the answer.